# Excel VBA InputBox Type:=0 | Formula entry not interactive

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am attempting to use an input box as part of my larger userform so that users can enter a formula for the first cell in a given range and that formula will be applied as part of an IFERROR formula to the larger range.  To define the formula, users hit a button in the user form which will then open an input box where Type = 8.

Normally, the user is able to select cells and type in the formula as if entering a formula into a cell but in this case, the input box acts like a static string.  The only way to interactively select a cell is to manually click on it which overwrites the entire formula.

The code is posted below, please let me know if there is something that I am doing wrong here or if there is some additional code that I could write to fix this.  Thank you.

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim errFormula As String

'runs after Make Formula Button is clicked in UserForm
Private Sub cmdBformula_Click()

    Dim newForm As String
    
    'defaults to errFormula if its already defined, will show empty if not written yet
    
    newForm = Application.InputBox("Enter Formula for " & Range(Replace(RefEdit1.Value, "$", ""))(1).Address(False, False) _
    & " : ", Title:="ERROR Value Formula Editor", Default:=errFormula, Type:=0)
    
    MsgBox VarType(newForm)
    errFormula = newForm

End Sub
```